# Ruby on Rails - Duplicate routes & impact on controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, controller

I am creating a Task Manager.

So, I have:

1. A dashboard where I can do CRUD for tasks (and then I will assign them a group)
2. A group section where I can go inside a group and do CRUD for tasks

Then my routes would look something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :groups, only: [ :index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy] do
        member do
          resources :tasks, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
        end
      end
      resources :tasks, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
    end
  end
end
```

For this:

1. A dashboard where I can do CRUD for tasks (and then I will assign them a group)

```
resources :tasks, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
```

And for this:

2. A group section where I can go inside a group and do CRUD for tasks

```
resources :groups, only: [ :index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy] do
  member do
    resources :tasks, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
  end
end
```

But I feel this is duplicating routes. I have 2 questions:

1. Is this the right approach or would there be a better way to solve it?
2. If I go with this, how would I approach the controller actions? Since in one situation (2) we would get the `params[:group_id]` but in the other I would need to add it as `strong_params`. Would an `if-else` condition work? (if there is no `[:group_id]` in `strong_params` then take the `params[:group_id]`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the right approach or would there be a better way to solve it?

No. Not really.

Deeply nested routes quickly become cumbersome to work with so you should consider using shallow nesting. This only nests the collection routes (index, new, create) and not the member routes (show, edit, update, destroy).

If tasks have a unique id you should be able to show, edit, update and destroy them without the group being involved. The exception to this rule is if tasks are only unique per group (but why?).

In an API this is especially true. The backend shouldn't need to know that you're modifying the resource from page X or Y in your frontend application.

You can use the `shallow: true` option to generate shallow routes but I would probally just define it as:

```ruby
# This respresents tasks not nested in a group
resources :tasks, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
 
resources :groups, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy] do
  resources :tasks, only: [:index, :create]
end
```

> If I go with this, how would I approach the controller actions?

There are really two different approaches here. One I call the "param sniffing method":

```
module API
  module V1
    class TasksController
      # GET /api/v1/groups/1/tasks
      # GET /api/v1/tasks
      def index
        if params[:group_id]
          render json: Group.find(params[:group_id]).tasks
        else
          render json: Task.all
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is the most obvious solution but blatantly violates the [Single Responsibity Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) and increases the cyclic complexity of all the methods.

The other solution is to route the nested representation of the resource to a separate controller:

```ruby
# This respresents tasks not nested in a group
resources :tasks, only: [:index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy]
 
resources :groups, only: [ :index, :show, :create, :update, :destroy] do
  resources :tasks, only: [:index, :create], module: :groups
end
```

This routes the `/groups/:group_id/tasks` routes into `API::V1::Groups::TasksController`.

```ruby
module API
  module V1
    class TasksController
      # GET /api/v1/tasks
      def index
        render json: Task.all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```ruby
module API
  module V1
    module Groups
      class TasksController
        before_action :set_group
 
        # GET /api/v1/groups/1/tasks
        def index
          render json: @group.tasks
        end

        private

        def set_group
          @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
        end 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You could also just do `resources :tasks, only: [:index, :create], controller: :group_tasks` if you want to avoid nesting the contants one more step.

Comment: Note that if you want to use the ideomatically correct API instead of Api (acronyms should be ALLCAPS) you need to setup an inflection with `inflect.acronym "API"`.

Comment: Great learning. Thank you very much for the explanations!